# VB.net/MS Access Monthly Donations System Assistance

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2016

I'm doing a project for my Database Management subject. I cannot figure out how to add an amount to a previously added amount. For now, I'm only able to update the amount. Here's the code. I'm sorry if I cannot explain it well.

I have 2 forms. My first form allows me to enter a last name and retrieve the data to my list view.

My second form lets me retrieve the data I entered in my first form and it will show up on a separate list view with a "Last Name | Amount" tab.

I have two textboxes. One for last name set to readonly to disable editing, and another for the amount I want to enter.

After entering an amount, let's say 20, it will update on the listview and my database as 20.

The problem is that when I enter a new amount for the same last name, let's say 30, the 30 will replace the 20 but it should be 50 because 20+30 = 50.

I understand the logic and I have tried adding another textbox for addition but I simply do not know the codes for it.

[image: This is Form 1: Adding of Last Name]

[image: This is form 2: Updating of Amount. Last Name set to readonly. No function for textbox3]

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2
Dim conString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Israel De Leon\Documents\testing.accdb;"
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString) 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database2.accdb
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()


Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'SET LISTVIEW PROPERTIES
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True

    'Construct Columns
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Last Name", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Amount", 100)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateLV(lname As String)
    'Updates last name and amount entered into the database
    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Table1 SET LastName='" + TextBox1.Text + "',Amount='" + TextBox2.Text + "' WHERE LastName='" + lname + "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    'OPEN CON, EXECUTE, UPDATE, CLOSE
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql

        If (adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated")

        End If

        con.Close()

        Retrieve()
        ClearBox()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Retrieve()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    'SQL STM
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 "
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    'OPEN CON, RETRIEVE, FILL LISTVIEW
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        adapter.Fill(dt)

        'LOOP THROUGH DT
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Populate(row(0), row(1)) 'Index of database row
        Next

        'CLEAR DATATABLE
        dt.Rows.Clear()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Populate(lname As String, aamount As String)
    'ROW ARRAY
    Dim row As String() = New String() {lname, aamount}

    Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(row)

    'ADD TO ROWS COLLECTION
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Retrieve()
End Sub
Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick
    Dim llname As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    Dim amounts As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text

    TextBox1.Text = llname
    TextBox2.Text = amounts
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim amounts As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    UpdateLV(amounts)
End Sub

Private Sub ClearBox()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This is a prototype by the way. Don't mind the design, I really need help with the functions. Thank you!!

Comment: Did you really have a database field named _Amounts_ of type string (text in access)?

Comment: @Steve  The data type is a Number good sir.

Comment: Yes adding textbox is correct, the only way that you can call it is you should sum the 2 values of textboxes then whenever you are updating the specific row, put your original amount to the 2nd textbox then add the revised amount to your original amount. You can do this directly on update command

Comment: Ah! It's still blurry in my head but let me translate what I read in layman's term and let me know if it is correct!

When I click on a last name, the amount goes to a textbox not connected to the database and the new amount I want to sum up will be the textbox that is actually connected to the database?

Comment: Get familiar with "database normalization" before creating a database. If you have a table for transactions, you can get a history of amounts. Don't rely on names to be unique. This should be done before coding.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical operation should not be done using strings. This is a real basic principle that many VB.NET programmers don't think enough thanks to the forgiveness allowed by Option Strict Off in the VB.NET project settings.
If you are just starting a new project in VB.NET don't use this setting but switch it ASAP to On. This will give you an halt when you try to use strings as they were numbers and force you to do the appropriate conversion and checking on the values provided.

So your code that updates the amount rewritten

```
Private Sub UpdateLV(lname As String)

    ' Get the amount as a number (decimal for currency is the best)
    Dim addAmt As Decimal
    if Not decimal.TryParse(textbox2.Text, addAmt) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert a valid amount please")
        return
    End If

    ' Sanity check 
    if addAmt <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Amount should be > 0")
        return
    End If

    'Updates last name and amount entered into the database
    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Table1 SET LastName=@name
                                ,Amount=Amount+@amt
                                 WHERE LastName=@oldname"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Try
        con.Open()

        ' Using an adapter here is wrong. You use directly the command
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@amt", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = addAmt
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@oldname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = lName
        If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
        End If
        con.Close()
        Retrieve()
        ClearBox()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Something else is not clear in your code. What is the purpose of changing also the LastName here? Finally do not keep a global connection object. Instead create it when you need it and destroy it afterward with Using statement. It will be better for your memory footprint and for your database

Comment: To be honest with you @Steve I was following a youtube guide for adding,updating, retrieving, and deleting and I simply translated what I learned to this prototype. My knowledge is limited and I don't quite understand your LastName question. If it's about the lname As String part, I've been asking myself why it's there. Conclusion i came up with is that it's there so that the last name row in my database can be called with the use of "WHERE". I'm trying to get through this subsystem as quickly as possible for our management system defense next week.

Comment: _`If you are just starting a new project in VB.NET don't use this setting but switch it ASAP to Off`_ - Don't you mean switch it to _**On**_?

Comment: @Steve I had to change the MessageBox to MsgBox and the cmd.parameters.Add("@amt", OleDbType.Decimal) = addAmt is giving me an error: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be target of an assignment"

Comment: @VisualVincent yes sorry fixed it now

Comment: @IzzyDeLeon fixed it now, missing the .Value part

Comment: The point abount lname/lastname. You set the LastName field with the value of your textbox1.Text but at the same time you retrieve the record to update searching for a LastName = lName. This doesn't make a lot of sense. If you know the name (lname is your search term) then unless you want to change that LastName to something different there is no need to SET LastName = textBox1.Text.

Comment: Last fix is MessageBox.Show. You could also use the old MsgBox function of VB6 but it is better if you go full NET instead and avoid obsolte functions still around for compatibility reasons

Comment: Apparently there is a syntax error in the update statement. I'm not very familiar with the codes you used.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there was no need for me to change the LastName at all?

Comment: If the variable _lname_ is initialized with the content of textbox1.Text, yes, it is the same value so searching LastName for the textbox1 and setting LastName to lname are a no op.